# openvpn client with two interface setup

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn

I have a openvpn client with two usb nic (interface). In normal situation, my client can connected to openvpn server by one interface (turning off the other nic).

How can I make the client use its both two interface connected to the vpn server? some of the configurations list below:

wlan0: 192.168.1.3
My pc is ubuntu 14.04, with Multipath TCP enabled. So it can aggregates bandwidth of two interfaces.

wlan1: 192.168.1.4

gateway: 192.168.1.1

**tunnel is over tcp**

other configurations are setup as default.

Thanks.

Comment: Your will need two openvpn connections (profiles) one with local 192.168.1.3 and another with local 192.168.1.4.

Comment: @citrin is it possible to use one openvpn (profile)? I mean to direct all the traffic from two interface to the vpn tunnel. thanks.

Comment: This isn't something you should be trying to make OpenVPN deal with.  You should be looking at setting up bonding or something at layer2.

Comment: @xiaobao-dan If server doesn't allow two connections from same client and server settings can't be changed, you can try to balance packets at L2 using firewall on both your PC (for outbound packets) and WiFi router (for incoming packets).